# Laravel subir archivos con Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile /tmp y enviar archivos adjuntos por correo ¿Dónde se guardan los archivos?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-6, laravel-7

He desarrollado un formulario dónde un usuario puede enviar archivos adjuntos, al procesar el formulario se valida y se manda por correo el archivo adjunto y la información del usuario.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ route('send.homework') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="exampleColorInput" class="form-label">Nombre de usuario</label>

                                <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control form-control-color"
                                    id="exampleColorInput"
                                    value="@if (Auth::user()->profile) {{ auth()->user()->profile->name }}
                                                @else{{ auth()->user()->username }} @endif"
                                    readonly ">
                                        </div>
        
                                        <div class="   form-group">

                                <label for="exampleColorInput" class="form-label">Tu correo</label>

                                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control form-control-color"
                                    id="exampleColorInput"
                                    value="{{ __(':email', ['email' => auth()->user()->email]) }}" readonly ">
                                
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="     form-group ">
                                <label for="exampleColorInput" class="form-label">Selecciona tu curso</label>
                                <select name="course" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                                    @foreach ($courses as $course)
                                        <option value="{{ $course->title }}">{{ $course->title }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Selecciona el archivo</label>
                                <input name="homework" type="file" class="form-control-file"
                                    id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button id="btn-danger" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                                    data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                <button type="submit" id="btn-primary" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    value="Enviar tarea">Enviar Tarea</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Este es el controlador que procesa los datos:

```
     <?php  namespace 

     App\Http\Controllers;
     
     use App\Models\User;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use App\Mail\SendContactForm;
     use App\Mail\SendHomeworkForm;
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

     class SendHomeworkController extends 
     Controller
     {
 public function sendHomework(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        "course" => "required",
        "homework" => "required",
    ]);

    $username = $request->input("username");
    $email = $request->input("email");
    $course = $request->input("course");
    $homework = $request->file('homework');

    $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
    // Check if uploaded file size was greater than 
    // maximum allowed file size
    if ($homework->getError() == 1) {
        $max_size = $homework->getMaxFileSize() / 10 / 5000;  // Get size in Mb
        $error = 'The document size must be less than ' . $max_size . 'Mb.';
        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_danger', $error);
    }

    $homework = [
        'homework' => $homework
    ];
    $username = [
        'username' => $username
    ];
    $email = [
        'email' => $email
    ];
    $course = [
        'course' => $course
    ];

    try {
        Mail::to('descubre@atecocolli.com')->send(new SendHomeworkForm($homework, $username, $email, $course));

        session()->flash("message", ["success", __("Tarea enviada")]);

        return back();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        session()->flash("message", ["danger", $exception->getMessage()]);
        return back();
    }
}
}
```

Esta es la clase mail que envía el archivo y los datos del usuario:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Mail;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

 class SendHomeworkForm extends Mailable
 {
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $homework;
public $username;
public $email;
public $course;
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($homework, $username, $email, $course)
{
    $this->homework = $homework;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->course = $course;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject("Tarea enviada desde - " . config("app.name"))
        ->markdown("emails.homework")->attach(
            $this->homework['homework']->getRealPath(),
            [
                'as' => $this->homework['homework']->getClientOriginalName(),
                'mime' => $this->homework['homework']->getClientMimeType(),
            ]
        );
}
}
```

Todo funciona bien el correo se envía con los datos del usuario y el archivo adjunto.

[image: correo-enviado-desde-app-laravel]

Pero si pongo dd(request()->all()); al inicio del método del controlador me manda la siguiente información:

[image: datos-request-all]

En la imagen del request me muestra lo siguientes:

- path: "/tmp"
- pathname: "/tmp/phpLyfxdJ"
- realPath: "/tmp/phpLyfxdJ"

El input con el name homework en el request muestra lo siguiente "homework" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile

Todo funciona pero mi duda es **¿Dónde se guardan los archivos?** busco en la carpeta de la distribución que utilizo basada en ubuntu en las siguientes carpetas /var/tmp y /tmp  pero no encuentro los archivos que acaban de ser enviados.

Comment: Ok entonces si entendí bien se envían por el correo y al final se borran sin hacer nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se guardan temporalmente en el folder /tmp y cuando se termine la ejecución del PHP, éste archivo se borrara inmediatamente; es por eso que el archivo siempre se mueve a otro directorio, para evitar perderlo.